# WordPress PHP (Events) error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So I'm working on some custom Events PHP in WordPress. It's made for the Events, and it will automatically bump off old dates. The issue is it won't order the dates in ascending order.

I'm not the best with PHP and got the help of the person who originally made it, and he wasn't sure why it it would order the dates correctly. I tried switching the `asc` to `desc` and it didn't change anything; there's a portion of the code I commented out some of the code, and I tried changing a lot of the code based on solutions I found online.

I'm running out of solutions so I'd appreciate assistance from any PHP wizards out there.

Here's the code relating to that part of the code.

```
function format_date($id=null, $string=null){
 if ( !is_null( $id ) )  {
    $date_of_event = get_post_field( 'date_of_event', $id );
    $date_of_event = strtotime($date_of_event);
    $event_date_pretty = date("l, F j, Y", $date_of_event);
 } else {
    //if $id was null and we have something for string use that else set $excerpt to '' so we can retrn nothing instead of an error.
    if ( !is_null( $string ) ) {
        $event_date_pretty = $string;
    }
    else {
        $event_date_pretty = '';
    }
 }

 return $event_date_pretty;
}

function events_func( $atts ) {
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'count' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'date_of_event',
    'order' => 'ASC',
), $atts );

if (!is_numeric($a['count']) || $a['count'] <= 0) { $a['count'] = 5; }
// $order = strtolower($a['order']);
// if ($order !== "ASC" && $order !== 'desc') { $a['order'] = "ASC"; }
// $a['order'] = strtoupper($a['order']); 

$type = 'event';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => $a['count'],
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
  'order' => $a['order'],
  'meta_key'=>$a['orderby'],
  'order' => 'meta_value',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass these arguments

```
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => $a['count'],
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
  'order' => $a['order'],
  'meta_key'=>$a['orderby'],
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
);
```